# WordPress customizer хук 'customize_preview_init'

Tags: wordpress

Почему если установить хук 'customize_preview_init' в условие if ($_GET['qwerty']) как в коде ниже то код не срабатывает, без условия if все работает. Возможно ли альтернатива как открыть customizer со своим сценарием.

```php
if ($_GET['qwerty']) {
    add_action( 'customize_preview_init', 'add_echo_preview'); //  не работает
    add_action( 'customize_controls_print_scripts', 'add_echo_panel') // работает
}
function add_echo_preview() {
    echo 'QWERTY';
}
function add_echo_panel() {
    echo 'QWERTY';
}
```

Использую ссылку для перехода:

```html
<a href=" <?= wp_customize_url() ?> ?qwerty=true" target="_blank">
http://localhost/wp/wp-admin/customize.php?qwerty=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том что "Customize Preview" загружается по домашней ссылке без учета GET. Я решил эту проблему так:

```
if ($_GET['qwerty']) {
  update_option('customizer_qwerty', 'true');
}
if (!is_customize_preview()) {
  update_option('customizer_qwerty', 'false');
}
if (get_option('customizer_qwerty') == 'true') {
  new CustomizerQwerty();
}
```